# what does jacoco yellow line mean

Tags: java, jacoco

I am trying to measure my code coverage using jacoco, but I dont understand the meaning of the yellow lines. The document says that it is for a condition which is not fully covered. But see the coverage snapshot I got - it is evident that the condition is hit because the subsequent line is green, so why is the condition marked as yellow?

[image: screen-shot]

Also, if you can point to a quick reference to what all coverage items that jacoco can show (besides line coverage) that will help a lot.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Take a look here: http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/counters.html:

> Partial coverage: Only a part of the instruction in the line have been executed

To turn green the condition should have been performed twice, one with false and one with true result. Probably your `args.equals("0")` always is true.